# Changing Masterpage of a Masterpage at Runtime in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know how to change the Masterpage of a Masterpage at Runtime. For a Page, there is a PreInit event where we can change the master page dynamically. No such event exists for the Masterpage. I also tried changing the masterpage in the Constructor of the base class, which too doesn't work.

Many Thanks,
Arun

Comment: I am deleting my answer. Will get back if I get a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your BasePage override `OnPreInit` method and assign the master page's master page as shown below

`this.Page.Master.MasterPageFile = "~/SuperSitem.master";`

Comment: accessing Page gives me a null object reference